# XSLT text for certain child XML

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to test of a certain XML not with certain content and attributes belonges to another XML node?

for example:

```
<a>
   <node/>
   <node>
      <node attr="attr1">
         <d>test</d>
      </node>
    </node>
   <node>
      <c attr="attr2">
         <d>test</d>
      </c>
   </node>
</a>
```

here I need to select only `<node>` nodes where child content is exactly

```
<node>
   <c attr="attr1">
      <d>test</d>
   </c>
</node>
```

Comment: Do you need to test 2 node values ex: test <d>test</d> and get only one <node>?

Comment: I need to test all nodes and get only those which have exact pre-defined content.

Comment: how about `//d[.='test']/../../node` will give you the exact `<node>` You can put this `//d[.='test']`equals true in the `xsl:if` condition to achieve your needs. I hope I have understood your requirement correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node[c[@attr = 'attr1'][d = 'test']]
```

would select nodes that contain *at least* that content, you'd have to add further constraints if you want *only* that content, e.g.

```
node[count(@*) = 0][count(node()) = 1]
  [c[count(@*) = 1][count(node()) = 1][@attr = 'attr1'][d[. = 'test'][not(*)]]
```

(this assumes your stylesheet has `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` so the whitespace-only text nodes can be ignored)